# Change background color invert text jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found some promising code to do random background css color and invert the text color but can not seem to get this to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var colors = ['#000000', '#FF3516', '#34FF17', '#2458FF'];
function UpdateColors() {
    $(this).each(function(index) {
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        var invertedColor = invertColor(color);
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': color,
            'color': invertedColor
        });
    });   
}
//$('div').UpdateColors();
});
```

Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/abennington/h49zh3gy/10/

Comment: where is method invertcolor

Comment: This [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h49zh3gy/12/) could be a possibilty to invoke the method with an element, but there is no function `invertColor` defined.

Comment: I've provided an answer below, however, there is no invertColor function defined. Let me know if you don't have the invertColor code and I'll add that function to the fiddle.

Comment: Looks like i missed that. Let me try and find that code...sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't extending jQuery so it couldn't see the $('div').UpdateColors() function.

I've tweaked that so you can use the function that way: `jQuery.fn.UpdateColors = function () { ... }`

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h49zh3gy/11/

However you will still get an error as the invertColor function is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be calling your `css()` method on a specific element or set of elements; `$(this)` won't work in the context in which you're using it.

So, since it looks like you're trying to do this for every element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ['#000000', '#FF3516', '#34FF17', '#2458FF'];
    $("*").each(function() {
        var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        var invertedColor = invertColor(color);
        $(this).css({ 'background-color': color, 'color': invertedColor });
    });
});
```

If you want to just do this on the body element, replace `"*"` with `"body"`.

(I'm assuming that your `invertColor()` function works.)

Edit: I think I missed your point a little. Once you extend `$`, you'll be able to call your function as you're doing in your commented-out call at the bottom. However, my code still works if you don't want to go the (in my opinion, slightly more fiddly) route of screwing around with `$`.